# How to not show Attachments from a certain Task on Account?

Tags: attachment, relationships, tasks

I have a Task that i create when quote is send out via email. The quote pdf is added to the task as a attachment. Since the task is related to opportunity and contact (through WhatId and WhoId) the attachment is available on opportunity and contacts. This is pretty fine. But unfortunately the AccountId of the task is automatically populated. Which results in a lot of attachments on a account. This makes is hard for users to find a attachment they are looking for.

The task [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_task.htm) says:

> AccountId Represents the ID of the related Account. The AccountId is determined as follows. If the value of WhatId is any of the following
>   objects, then Salesforce uses that object’s AccountId.
>
> - Account
> - Opportunity
> - Contract
> - Custom object that is a child of Account
>
> If the value of the WhatIdfield is any other object, and the value of
>   the WhoId field is a Contact object, then Salesforce uses that
>   contact’s AccountId. (If your organization uses Shared Activities,
>   then Salesforce uses the AccountId of the primary contact.)
>
> Otherwise, Salesforce sets the value of the AccountId field to null.

My question is: Is there a way how i can keep the attachment on contacts and opportunities but don't add it to accounts?

Comment: So, you're saying the PDF gets attached to Opp, the Contact and to the Account even though those objects are already on the Account's related lists because it's attached to an Activity related to the Account?

Comment: yes that is right. It is fine that the it is shown on the Opportunity and on the Contact but i would like to not show it on the Account or not relate it to the Account at all.

Comment: Does the Quote need to be attached to the Task instead of just being associated with or attached to the Opportunity? The Task really only needs to show that the email was sent and when. Does it really need to include the email and it's attachments if it's in the Opportunity? It seems as though you're keeping records in quadruplicate here (the Quote is already there on the related list of Opportunity).

Comment: You are right that it generates a lot of records and i totally agree that it is not the best way to do it. It was not my decision to do it like that and unfortunately i have to keep it that way. :-(

Comment: Perhaps you need to explain the impact on the database to your management and the references that already exist between the records to the quote? That decision is ultimately the source of the problem that you're having. In Salesforce workflow (not referring to rules here), Quote wasn't intended to be attached to a task.